# Why is cell "A1" being used in this GetValue function in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this function to retrieve a value from a closed workbook. In this 8th line of this code, I don't understand why "A1" is being used. What exactly is happening in that entire 8th line? I'm confused by the xlR1C1 argument as well.

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)

    Dim arg As String
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
      Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)

End Function
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, but it might be in case `ref` is a collection of cells, so it will always return a value.

Comment: We would need to see the `ExecuteExcel4Macro()` code to see what input it needs.  But the syntax after `.Address()` is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821207%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: ExecuteExcel4Macro is -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193589%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Although if you're still using Excel 4 macros now ... might be time to upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

`Range().Range()` [Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834676%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

> When applied to a `Range` object, the property is relative to the `Range` object. For example, if the selection is cell `C3`, then `Selection.Range("B1")` returns cell `D3` because it’s relative to the `Range` object returned by the `Selection` property. On the other hand, the code `ActiveSheet.Range("B1")` always returns cell `B1`.

The code is using that second `Range("A1")` to ensure that if you have a `ref` range larger than one cell, it only returns the top left cell of that range.  Also it would appear your other `Sub` called `ExecuteExcel4Macro()` requires an `R1C1` type cell reference so the address is being converted into that type for passing the `arg` string into the `Sub`.

Answer (score 1):

`xlR1C1` is a [reference style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlreferencestyle%28v=office.15%29.aspx) which is used to specify how formulas work. When using this style, your formulas will work and look very differently than you expect. The R1C1 specification, basically means the cells are referred to differently using row & column ordinals instead of letter names. For example, when using xlR1C1, you would access cell B2 by using `=R2C2` (row2, column 2). Another Example, cell C10 could be referred to as `=R10C3`

As to whats happening on line 8... you are constructing a cell reference that looks like this: (Note that your cell reference will be different because it has a file path in it)

```
='[Myfilename.xlsx]Sheet1'!R1C1
```

You can use the debugger to view the string contained in the `arg` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `Range("A1")` to the code doesn't appear to do anything at all. Typing this into the immediate window results in some... unexpected results.

```
?Range("B3").Range("A1").Address
$B$3
```

Now, I would have expected that to return `$A$1`, but it seems that this part of the function will return the address of `Range(ref)`.

Now, calling [`Range.Address`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625(v=office.15).aspx) with the [ReferenceStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlreferencestyle%28v=office.15%29.aspx) argument would produce these results.

```
?Range("B3").Range("A1").Address(,,xlR1C1)
R3C2
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything to a single cell range, but for a multi cell range (i.e. Range("C3:H99")) it returns the top left cell.

Comment: I actually just learned that @Tmdean. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27828218/3198973