# Why does Range.Address() return the address of the first cell when chained?

Tags: vba, excel, method-chaining

I stumbled across some unexpected behavior when writing [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27827942/3198973) for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27827384/3198973).

When chaining together `Range` calls, `Address` always returns the address of the very first `Range` object in the statement. For example:

```
Public Sub Unexpected()

    Debug.Print Range("B3").Address
    Debug.Print Range("B3").Range("A1").Address

End Sub
```

Returns the following output.

```
$B$3
$B$3
```

But I would have expected it to return the Address of the *last* Range object in the chain.

```
$B$3
$A$1
```

Can anyone explain this behavior? Preferably with a quote of and link to the appropriate documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is documentation on using `Range().Cells()` which indicates that `Cells()` will return the location within the given `Range()` relative to the top left cell of the `Range()`.  Testing this theory with `Range().Range()` gives:

```
Public Sub Unexpected()

    Debug.Print Range("B1:C3").Range("A1").Address
        '$B$1
    Debug.Print Range("B1:C3").Range("B1").Address
        '$C$1
End Sub
```

[Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834676%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

> When applied to a `Range` object, the property is relative to the `Range` object.
>
> For example, if the selection is cell `C3`, then `Selection.Range("B1")` returns cell `D3` because it’s relative to the `Range` object returned by the `Selection` property. On the other hand, the code `ActiveSheet.Range("B1")` always returns cell `B1`.